# Tableview lines show trough loading view

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiview

**Situation**:
I'm trying to display a loading screen while waiting for my asynchronous connection to return with data to populate the tableview.

**Problem**:
Creating and adding the loadingscreen works fine, however, the tableview draws its lines over it, see screenshot:

[image: the problem]
.

**Code**: I add the view with these lines:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _loadScreen = [[LoadScreen alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.view addSubview: _loadScreen];
    [self fetchRemoteData];
}
```

**Question**: Is it possible to add the loading view ontop of the table? Or can i make sure the tableview does not draw its lines untill i call reloadData?

-Thanks in advance,
W

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done it like this many times:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _loadScreen = [[LoadScreen alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.tableView addSubview: _loadScreen];
    self.tableView.hidden = YES;
    [self fetchRemoteData];

}

- (void)dataFetchedSuccessfully
{
    self.tableView.hidden = NO;
}
```

Just hide the tableview and show it again when the data has been loaded.

Comment: Ah, splendid! Sometimes the anwser is more simple than you imagine:)

Answer (score 0):

There is some approaches that will solve you problem:

-Set a footer view for the table view, so all lines should disappear.

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
```

-I assume that you use UItableViewController. If so self.view and self.tableView both represents the same view, so by setting:

```
self.tableView.hidden = NO;
```

It will hide even your loading view. What I encoure you to do is to create a custom view which has an table view as its subview. Then you can hide this table view by only showing an loading view.

Hope I could help.

Comment: You assumed correctly. But I already had it fixed. I indeed had to change the class to a uiviewcontroller with a uitableview in it. I only alloc and add the tableView when the connection returns. (Nick's anwser made me realize that i had to do this because hiding the view from a tableviewcontroller hides all views in it.)